# How to keep boxed objects in heap until the end of program execution?

Tags: rust, memory-management

I'm doing this, for experimental purposes (I want to allocate many objects in heap and measure the performance of this):

```
struct Foo {
    x: u32
}

for i in 0..1000 {
  let b = Box::new(Foo {x: i as u32});
  let p = b.deref();
  println!("Pointer: {:p}", p);
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
Pointer: 0x600000780000
Pointer: 0x600000780000
Pointer: 0x600000780000
Pointer: 0x600000780000
Pointer: 0x600000780000
...
```

Obviously, all addresses are the same, which means that right after an object is allocated it gets destroyed. How to prevent this? I want to keep the memory occupied by objects, not freed immediately.

Comment: `let p = b.deref()` is pretty redundant since [`Box` implements `std::fmt::Pointer`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Pointer.html#impl-Pointer-for-Box%3CT%2C%20A%3E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) to ensure the box doesn't get freed.

```rust
fn main() {
    struct Foo {
        x: u32
    }

    for i in 0..1000 {
        let b = Box::new(Foo {x: i as u32});
        let p = Box::leak(b);
        println!("Pointer: {:p}", p);
    }
}
```

More generally [`std::mem::forget`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.forget.html) can be used to not run destructors

Answer (score 1):

To not free an object the best approach is to move it somewhere where it is in scope:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut items = Vec::with_capacity(1000);
    for x in 0..1000 {
        let b = Box::new(Foo {x});
        println!("Pointer: {:p}", b);
        items.push(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: This `items.push()` call will significantly affect my performance calculations. I'm interested to measure purely the speed of memory allocations, without anything else.

Comment: It's an add plus a move, I'm pretty sure next to the `println!()` it's negligible.

Comment: You are right, but in my real experiment I'm not using `println!()`, only `deref`